# Storing 2 strings in 2 separate variables from text file

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a text file that has the following in it:
`A,B:C,D`

I know that if I didn't have the colon and just had A,B, I could do

```
infile = open(filename, "r")
readfile = infile.readlines()
AB = readfile[0]
for x in AB:
    stripab = AB.strip()
    A, B = AB.split(",")
    # Want to add the two to a list after
    mydict[A] = B
```

How would I be able to split C,D and store them into the same variables as A,B in order to add them to the dictionary?

Comment: You can use [`re.split("[,:]")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split).

Comment: Why do you have the `for x in AB` loop? This seems useless. Also, please provide the expected output (content of `mydict`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same thing as in your example, but twice:

```
infile = open(filename, "r")
readfile = infile.readlines()
AB = readfile[0]

stripab = AB.strip()
firstSplit = stripab.split(":")
A, B = firstSplit[0].split(",")
C, D = firstSplit[1].split(",")
mydict[A] = B
mydict[C] = D
```

Answer (score 0):

If "A,B:C,D" is just the first line in your opened file, then you don't need to run a for loop. Simple if-else logic below should work.

```
infile = open(filename, "r")
readfile = infile.readlines()
AB = readfile[0]
lst = AB.strip().split(':')
if len(lst) == 2:
    A, B = lst[0].split(',')
    mydict[A] = B
    C, D = lst[1].split(',')
    mydict[C] = D
elif len(lst) == 1:
    A, B = lst[0].split(',')
    mydict[A] = B
```